# RTransferEntropy: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument

Tags: r, entropy

I am having some issues computing Transfer Entropy.

I have no problem following the example in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTransferEntropy/vignettes/transfer-entropy.html).

Here is my problem. I create the following vectors subsetted from actual data.

```r
x <- c(79652133, 88786612, 95234422, 99336996, 100764257, 105189366, 121472911, 
       119542332, 119862125, 120657508, 124405340, 125345113, 132920670)

y <- c(211363, 217291, 226623, 230039, 239212, 247339, 255805, 264450, 282990, 
       304316, 314135, 313509, 331670)

te_result <- transfer_entropy(x, y, nboot = 100)
te_result
```

```
Shannon's entropy on 1 core with 100 shuffles.
  x and y have length 14 (0 NAs removed)
  [calculate] X->Y transfer entropy
  [calculate] Y->X transfer entropy
  [bootstrap] 100 times
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
> te_result
Shannon Transfer Entropy Results:
-----------------------------------------------------------
Direction        TE   Eff. TE  Std.Err.   p-value    sig
-----------------------------------------------------------
     X->Y    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    ***
     Y->X    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    ***
-----------------------------------------------------------
Bootstrapped TE Quantiles (100 replications):
-----------------------------------------------------------
Direction      0%     25%     50%     75%    100%
-----------------------------------------------------------
     X->Y  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
     Y->X  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
-----------------------------------------------------------
Number of Observations: 13
-----------------------------------------------------------
p-values: < 0.001 '***', < 0.01 '**', < 0.05 '*', < 0.1 '.'
```

The algorithm works fine. However, if I add an additional element to both vectors x and y, I get an error:

```
x <- c(79652133, 88786612, 95234422, 99336996, 100764257, 105189366, 121472911, 
       119542332, 119862125, 120657508, 124405340, 125345113, 132920670, 137487222)

y <- c(211363, 217291, 226623, 230039, 239212, 247339, 255805, 264450, 282990, 
       304316, 314135, 313509, 331670, 348884)

te_result <- transfer_entropy(x, y, nboot = 100)
te_result
```

```
Shannon's entropy on 1 core with 100 shuffles.
  x and y have length 14 (0 NAs removed)
  [calculate] X->Y transfer entropy
  [calculate] Y->X transfer entropy
  [bootstrap] 100 times
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

Any idea? Is that a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug in the current version. I have opened this issue to debug and further discuss: https://github.com/BZPaper/RTransferEntropy/issues/58